# Shape Layer won't Align to composition

Tags: after-effects

I have a stroke in my composition, and the anchor point of the stroke is set to the middle of the stroke.

I'm trying to use the Align Panel functions to bring the stroke to the middle of the composition, but it won't work. I can't seem to understand why.
[image]

Comment: Coudl you add a screenshot showing the Shape details, the "Transform: Shape 1" and "Transform" properties fully expanded?